# What happens if you removed .gitignore?

Tags: github, github-for-mac

Just as the title states, I am curious as to what happens if you removed the .gitignore file. Since I am a beginner, I have absolutely no clue where this file is stored and I am also asking because there is a good chance that I might have removed it by accident by not following instructions (and not reading the instructions as I used them).

My whole repo is officially ruined, I have a ton of untracked files appearing when I do 'git status' that didn't used to appear before this. What do I do ? Is all this happening because I deleted .gitignore? I might've deleted it because one of my 'git push' commands recommended that I deleted it and what not. Thanks in advance..

Comment: It is simply a list of filenames or patterns for git to ignore.  You could revert the deletion or just recreate the file to ignore all of the untracked files again.

Comment: how would I revert the deletion? It's been days since I messed it up, can I still fix it?

Comment: This isn't really the place for a git tutorial.  If the file existed in your repository it can be recovered.  I suggest you read a bit more about git and source control in general.

Comment: I took your advice, it worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah your gitignore does what it says, it ignores certain files/file types so they don't show up one your github. You'd have to make a new .gitignore file or you could try this site:
[gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io/)

Answer (score 1):

The .gitignore file will specify patterns that if any files in your working directory match them, they should not be considered for the repo. You can always recreate this file manually.